# How do I lead client to another page and modify an uploaded file in the code-behind in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Right now in my HTML I have:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="pbcUploadBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="uploadBtnClick" />
```

In my code-behind:

```
protected void uploadBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        this.fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + this.fileUpload.FileName);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to, on the click of the button, call javascript to lead the user to the next page (FileEditor.aspx). I need to lead the user to the next page while keeping the filename so it can operate on it with XmlDocument methods. How do I pass back the GUID generated in the uploadBtnClick() method? I'm guessing the second page will have another code-behind, so I'm not sure how I can operate on that specific file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you save the uploaded file, you can use [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx) to load the next page in your flow without changing the URL. This will, however, still cause the page to go through the entire ASP.NET life cycle.

Comment: regarding your last line, I'm assuming that you wouldn't recommend this?

Comment: I would use it as long as it didn't cause a side effect that breaks things. I just wanted you to be aware that entire page life cycle would still occur.